# Win7: Wake linux server when accessing share

Tags: windows, network-shares, wake-on-lan

I have a small home server running archlinux mostly for file storage. Although the server does not consume a lot of power I would like to keep it suspended most of the time and only wake it when someone actually tries to access it.

I can suspend the server and wake it by explicitly sending a magic packet from my fritzbox 7490. How can I configure Windows (7 and 10) to send such a packet when accessing a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Configure Linux to wake up on other activities too, not only magic packets:
  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#Software_configuration
- Configure the fritzbox to wake PC on traffic (same settings page as for waking up explicitly)
- Try to configure Windows to send a magic packet to the Linux PC when needed. This has some problems though

  - if the PCs do not share the LAN, you most likely need to send the package to your fritzbox and make it forward it to broadcast -- which fritzboxes do not allow.
  - You need to somehow try to run a service for Windows which detects network-filesystem usage. Crafting the magic packet is probably comparable easy.